# Practical Use of Zero-Length Bitfields

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

I am not totally sure about C, but C++ allows unnamed bit-fields of 0 length. For example:

```
struct X
{
    int : 0;
};
```

- **Question one: What practical uses of this can *you* think of?**
- **Question two: What real-world practical uses (if any) are you aware of?**

***Edited*** the example after ice-crime's answer

***Edit:*** OK, thanks to the current answers I now know the theoretical purpose. But the questions are about practical uses so they still hold :)

Comment: C99 allows zero-length arrays to better support dynamically sized structures.

Comment: @roe: Yeah, well, it is the equivalent of 0-length dynamically allocated arrays, which are really useful. I think that the problem here is that the bit-field length must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @roe: Your comment is incorrect. C **does not allow** `char a[0];` in any version of the standard. On the other hand, `char a[];` is allowed in structures in C99; it is called a flexible array member and must appear at the end. `char a[];` is **not** a "shorthand for `char a[0];`".

Comment: @R, my bad I was mistaken; using zero is a GCC specific extension. It still technically is a zero-length array though which the original question stated was not possible. I am aware that it must be at the end of a structure (anywhere else would make no sense whatsoever).

Comment: @R: It's too bad C required arrays to have non-zero size, since the popularity of the most common hack to work around the prohibition against zero-sized arrays prevents compilers from making some otherwise-useful optimizations.  For example, if struct foo ends with "int bar[1]", the expression "foo.bar[i]" could legally be replaced with "foo.bar[0]" which could be evaluated at compile time (since any other value of "i" would invoke Undefined Behavior).  Of course, the struct hack is sufficiently common that any compiler which took advantage of such an optimization would break real-world code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You use a zero-length bitfield as a hacky way to get your compiler to lay out a structure to match some external requirement, be it another compiler's or architecture's notion of the layout (cross-platform data structures, such as in a binary file format) or a bit-level standard's requirements (network packets or instruction opcodes).

A real-world example is when NeXT ported the xnu kernel from the Motorola 68000 (m68k) architecture to the i386 architecture. NeXT had a working m68k version of their kernel. When they ported it to i386, they found that the i386's alignment requirements differed from the m68k's in such a way that an m68k machine and an i386 machine did not agree on the layout of the NeXT vendor-specific BOOTP structure. In order to make the i386 structure layout agree with the m68k, they added an unnamed bitfield of length zero to force the `NV1` structure/`nv_U` union to be 16-bit aligned.

Here are the relevant parts from the Mac OS X 10.6.5 xnu source code:

```
/* from xnu/bsd/netinet/bootp.h */
/*
 * Bootstrap Protocol (BOOTP).  RFC 951.
 */
/*
 * HISTORY
 *
 * 14 May 1992 ? at NeXT
 *  Added correct padding to struct nextvend.  This is
 *  needed for the i386 due to alignment differences wrt
 *  the m68k.  Also adjusted the size of the array fields
 *  because the NeXT vendor area was overflowing the bootp
 *  packet.
 */
/* . . . */
struct nextvend {
  u_char nv_magic[4]; /* Magic number for vendor specificity */
  u_char nv_version;  /* NeXT protocol version */
  /*
   * Round the beginning
   * of the union to a 16
   * bit boundary due to
   * struct/union alignment
   * on the m68k.
   */
  unsigned short  :0;
  union {
    u_char NV0[58];
    struct {
      u_char NV1_opcode;  /* opcode - Version 1 */
      u_char NV1_xid; /* transcation id */
      u_char NV1_text[NVMAXTEXT]; /* text */
      u_char NV1_null;  /* null terminator */
    } NV1;
  } nv_U;
};
```

Comment: We probably shouln't use term `hacky`. There is a strict rule in standard how this works .

Answer (score 29):

The standard (9.6/2) only allows 0 length bit-fields as a **special case** :

> As a special case, an unnamed
>   bit-field with a width of zero
>   specifies alignment of the next
>   bit-field at an allocation unit
>   boundary. **Only when declaring an
>   unnamed bit-field may the
>   constant-expression be a value equal
>   to zero**.

The only use is described in this quote, although I've never encountered it in practical code yet.

---

For the record, I just tried the following code under VS 2010 :

```
struct X {
    int i : 3, j : 5;
};

struct Y {
    int i : 3, : 0, j : 5; // nice syntax huh ?
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(X) << " - " << sizeof(Y) << std::endl;
}
```

The output on my machine is indeed : `4 - 8`.

Comment: A practical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-it-in-c-code

Answer (score 12):

```
struct X { int : 0; };
```

is undefined behavior in C.

See (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p2) "The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for the members of the structure or union. **If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined**"

(C11 has the same wording.)

You can use an unnamed bit-field with `0` width but not if there is no other named member in the structure.

For example:

```
struct W { int a:1; int :0; };  // OK
struct X { int :0; };           // Undefined Behavior
```

By the way for the second declaration, `gcc` issues a diagnostic (not required by the C Standard) with `-pedantic`.

On the other hand:

```
 struct X { int :0; };
```

is defined in GNU C. It is used for example by the Linux kernel (`include/linux/bug.h`) to force a compilation error using the following macro if the condition is true:

```
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

Comment: +1; perhaps you could mention that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code describes that macro in more detail.

Comment: For ``BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO``'s sake I'd hope that that struct remains defined in GnuC and I use ``static_assert`` in my own code to make sure it does! It certainly doesn't seem to be on, say, msvc. Using v19.14 under godbolt.org,  the sizeof: ``struct { int:0; }`` is 4 (0 under gcc) while, curiously, the sizeof both ``struct { char c; int:0; }``  and ``struct { int:0; char c; }`` is 1 (both 4 under gcc). The latter looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm curious how do you know that `struct X { int :0; };` is defined in GCC, and not UB? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is from MSDN and not marked as Microsoft Specific, so I guess this is common C++ standard:

An unnamed bit field of width 0 forces alignment of the next bit field to the next type boundary, where type is the type of the member.

Answer (score 2):

The C11 standard now allows the inclusion of zero length bitfields. Here is an example from the C Committee draft (N1570), which I believe illustrates a practical usage.

> **3.14 memory location**
>   ...
>   4. EXAMPLE A structure declared as
>
> ```
> struct {
>   char a;
>   int b:5, c:11, :0, d:8;
>   struct { int ee:8; } e;
> }
> ```
>
> contains four separate memory locations: The member `a`, and bit-fields `d` and `e.ee` are each separate memory locations, *and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other*. The bit-fields `b` and `c` together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields `b` and `c` cannot be concurrently modified, but `b` and `a`, for example, can be.

So including the zero length bitfield in between the bitfields `c` and `d` allows the concurrent modification of `b` and `d` as well.