# C++11 memory model and accessing different members of the same struct in different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, memory-model

Assume you've got the following definitions:

```
struct X
{
  char a, b;
};

X x;
```

And now assume you have two threads, one of which reads and writes `x.a` but never accesses `x.b` while the other one reads and writes `x.b` but never accesses `x.a`. Neither thread uses any locks or other synchronization primitives. Is this guaranteed to work in C++11? Or does it count as accessing the same object, and therefore need a lock?

Comment: It's fine, they are two distinct locations. I'll leave someone with the energy to prove it to answer.

Comment: @Mat But every object/primitive in C/C++ is required to be at least 1 byte. And 1 byte is the "smallest addressable unit".

Comment: The answer's in there somewhere I think http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware-herb-sutter

Comment: @Mat I remember hearing somewhere that the standard requires that all field members have different addresses. Although this is 3rd hand info I heard from chat. I'll wait for someone to confirm/deny it.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for that interesting link. I just watched part 1;  while the answer to my question wasn't in that, I learned a lot of other stuff from it.

Comment: Note that although this is safe, it will likely result in [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) and degrade performance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's safe. Quoting C++11:

[intro.memory]p3:

> A *memory location* is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. [ *Note:* Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might involve additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation. *—end note* ] Two threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

[intro.memory]p5:

> [ *Example:* A structure declared as

```
struct {
  char a;
  int b:5,
  c:11,
  :0,
  d:8;
  struct {int ee:8;} e;
}
```

> contains four separate memory locations: The field `a` and bit-fields `d` and `e.ee` are each separate memory locations, and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields `b` and `c` together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields `b` and `c` cannot be concurrently modified, but `b` and `a`, for example, can be. *—end example* ]

These together mean that the members `a` and `b` of `X` are separate memory locations, and can thus be accessed concurrently.

Comment: What is that `:0`, does this force a byte boundary?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Pretty much. It's a *zero-length bit field.* Quoting `[class.bit]p2`: "As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment of the next bit field at an allocation unit boundary."

Comment: [Found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802728/what-is-zero-width-bit-field/13802955#13802955)

Comment: What if it was `unsigned int c:11` instead of `int c:11`? Does the fact that the type of the bitfield changes matter?

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't really know - bit fields are weird beasts.

Comment: It is safe. But because a and b are in the same cache line. Each read and write when the other thread wrote to it last will incur a performance hit because it needs to flush the cache line.