# Structure declaration

Tags: c, structure

There is a structure declaration like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a:1;
    :0;
    int b:2;
} struct1;
```

I don't understand how to read it or understand it, I don't understand the following:

1) `struct1` is a data type containing an integer `a` and b of two bytes each of only 1 and 2 bits are accessible respectively,

2) What does `:0` mean?

3) Is there any difference between `struct{ int a;int b;}struct1;` and the above `typedef`?

4) If I am create a variable like `struct1 c={1,2,4};` it gives me error "too many initializers"

Comment: Look up "bit fields". This is all well documented, standard C.

Comment: [Bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

Comment: [This](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03defbitf.htm) should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called bit fields. It's a way to specify how many bits should be assigned to each variable in the structure.

1. They are not "two bytes", nothing in the code says that. Also a signed integer of width 1 is a very bad idea, it will only be able to store the values -1 and 0.
2. The anonymous bit field `:0` causes the following bit field to be allocated into a distinct `int`. [See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx) for details.
3. Yes, the above uses bit fields, which will affect how accesses to `a` and `b` are done.
4. Yes, there are only two fields in the struct, `a` and `b`. Not three.

Comment: That means int a is taking 1 byte (int size is reduced due to the bit field width) and int b is also taking 1 byte, so the size of the data type is 2 bytes.If there is no :0 then int b will get place in the same first 8 bits(i think so and data type size will be 1 byte.).

Answer (score 0):

The members in struct1 declared that way is called "bit-fields".As the name indicates, those members only occupy several bits length in memory. The number of bit they really occupied and they can occupied depend on the number behide the ":" and the ABI respectly.

So,

```
struct bits_A {
    int a:10;
};
```

"a" is a 10 bit length member.

While,

```
struct bits_B {
    int a:64;
};
```

cannot be successfully compiled (error "error: width of ‘a’ exceeds its type") by the x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc linux compile tool, because in x86_64, the bit-field length can only be equal of or smaller than 32.

The "bit-field" is a very hard part of the c programming language, because the bit-field implement differs with the compile tools, the ABI and the Endian.

So,

1. The struct1 is a struct containing two members: 1 bit length member "a" and 2 bit length member "b". the ":0" is a 0 length bit-field indicates the compile tool not to merge "a" with "b" in the same int so it is not a real member.
2. According to 1, a 0 length bit-field is only a flag indicating the compile tool not to merge "a" with "b" in the same int. A more precise explanation is in [What is zero-width bit field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802728/what-is-zero-width-bit-field).
3. In struct{ int a;int b;}struct1;, "struct1" is a variable. While keyword "typedef" only defines a new type.
4. There are only two member in struct1, please see No.2.