# What's the use of initializing blank bitfields

Tags: c++, bit-fields

So I was learning about bitfields, and when I stumbled upon [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), I saw

```cpp
unsigned char :0; // start a new byte
```

I'm wondering why that would be used, since it's wasting memory. Does it have a practical use? Where would it be used practically?

Edit: So I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297095/practical-use-of-zero-length-bitfields), but is there any practical use other than cross-compiler compatibility?

Comment: Hard to say without context, but maybe the reason was to get a specific memory layout for serialization purposes (altough this is not the only problem to overcome for good serialization...)

Comment: And also [this So question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802728/what-is-zero-width-bit-field)

Answer (score 0):

Standard actually explains this:

> 6.7.2.1 p12:
>
> A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a width, indicates an
>   unnamed bit-field.126) As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bit-
>   field, if any, was placed.
>
> 126: *An unnamed bit-field structure member is useful for padding to conform to externally imposed layouts.*