# Signed bit field represetation

Tags: c, bit-fields

I made a bit field with a field sized 1 bit, and used `int` instead of `unsigned`. Later on when i tried to check the value of the field i found that the value was -1. 
I used this code to check the binary represantation and the value of my bit field:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union {
    struct {
        int bit:1;
    } field;
    int rep;
} n;

int main() {

int c, k;
n.field.bit=1;
 for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    k = n.rep >> c;

    if (k & 1)
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  }

  printf("\n %d \n", n.field.bit);

return 0;
}
```

the output was:
00000000000000000000000000000001

-1

In that case, why is the value of my bit field is -1 and is it always be a negative number when i use signed int instead of unsigned ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You should never use plain `int` as the bitfield type if you're expecting something about the value** besides that it can hold `n` bits - according to the C11 standard it is actually implementation-defined whether `int` in a bit-field is signed or unsigned [6.7.2p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p5):

> 5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is **implementation-defined** whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

In your case the `int` designates the same type as `signed int`; this is [the default in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html):

> *Whether a “plain” int bit-field is treated as a signed int bit-field or as an unsigned int bit-field (C90 6.5.2, C90 6.5.2.1, C99 and C11 6.7.2, C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).*
>
> By default it is treated as `signed int` but this may be changed by the `-funsigned-bitfields` option.

Thus any sane program always specifies **either** `signed int` or `unsigned int`, depending on which is appropriate for the current use case.

---

Then it is implementation defined whether the signed numbers are in one's complement, or two's complement - or perhaps sign and magnitude - if they're in one's complement or s-and-m, then the only value that can be stored in 1 bit is the sign bit, thus 0; so signed bit field of one bit probably makes sense only with 2's complement.

Your system seems to use 2's complement - this is e.g. [what GCC always uses](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> *Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude, two’s complement, or one’s complement, and whether the extraordinary value is a trap representation or an ordinary value (C99 and C11 6.2.6.2).*
>
> GCC supports only two’s complement integer types, and all bit patterns are ordinary values.

and thus the bit values `1` and `0` are interpreted in terms of signed two's complement numbers: the former has sign bit set, so it is negative (`-1`) and the latter doesn't have a sign bit set so it is non-negative (`0`).

Thus for a signed bit-field of 2 bits, the possible bit patterns and their integer  values on a 2's complement machine are

- `00` - has `int` value 0
- `01` - has `int` value 1
- `10` - has `int` value -2
- `11` - has `int`  value -1

In an n-bit-field, the minimum signed number is - 2^(n - 1) and the maximum is 2^(n-1) - 1.

Now, when arithmetic is performed on a signed integer operand whose rank is less than `int`, it is converted to an `int` first, and thus the value `-1` is sign-extended to full-width `int`; the same happens for *default argument promotions*; the value is sign-extended to a (full-width) `int` when it is passed in to `printf`.

Thus if you expect a sensible value from one bit bitfield, use either `unsigned bit: 1;` or alternatively if this is to be understood as a boolean flag, `_Bool bit: 1;`

Comment: When you layer it on top of everything else that's implementation-defined in regard to bit-fields, their usefulness diminishes quite alot

Comment: As far as I know, the one's complement representation is vastly unused.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well that's why my previous revision already mentioned that two's complement is the one used by GCC ... so any host targetted with GCC will use two's complement. To my knowledge there are no compilers that support more architectures than GCC.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a variadic argument function (like `printf`) some arguments are *promoted*. For example bit-fields undergoes an [*integer promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) where it is promoted to an ordinary `int` value. That promotion brings with it *sign extension* (because your base type for the bit-field is signed). This sign extension will make it `-1`.

When using bit-fields, almost always use unsigned types as the base.

Comment: Can i expect evety bit field to be negative when called to with printf ?

Comment: @tomslu Depends on the base-type, its width and its value. And on the compiler (according to [Antti Haapala's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527500/440558)).

Comment: "always use unsigned types as the base": why ? If you do need signed integers use signed integers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe I shouldn't have said "always", but the number of use-cases for signed values in a bit-field is very *very* small.

Comment: I certainly agree for 1-bit fields. For larger sizes, the fields are in fact often used as enumerated values, for which signedness is irrelevant, and hopefully consistently handled by the compiler. For truly numerical bit fields, who knows...