# How can I represent all the possible values of n bits in base 2 using n bits in C?

Tags: c, field, bit

I defined the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int unused :8;
    int group  :2;
    int opcode :4;
    int source_mode :2;
    int   dest_mode :2;
    int   are       :2;

}first_word;
```

I want each field to be able to hold all of the possible values that can be represented using the bits it received in the structure, in base 2.

For example:

The possible values of a field containing 2 bits would be:

```
00  /*0 in base 2*/
01  /*1 in base 2*/
10  /*2 in base 2*/
11  /* 3 in base 2 */
```

Since 10 in decimal is represented using 4 bits in base 2, I cannot do this:

```
int main()
{ 
     first_word fw;
     fw.group = 10;
     return 0;
}
```

because otherwise, I'd get the following error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:17: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
      fw.group = 10;
                ^~
```

Similarly, I want the opcode to be able to hold all the possible values using 4 bits, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `int group  :4;`...... Not clear for me...

Comment: I want group to contain 2 bits only, so I used bit fields @LPs

Comment: You can start by making the fields unsigned, since that's what you claim to be after anyway.

Comment: You used two bits, so why on earth are you complaining it can't hold 10?

Comment: I meant in base 2. 10 in base 2 is 2 in decimal.

Comment: Unclear: `opcode` _is_ 4 bits wide, and can already hold decimal 10; `group` is only 2 bits wide, why are you assigning `fw.group = 10;`?

Comment: That was a long exposition just to ask a completely unrelated question. C has no binary integer constants.

Comment: If I treat 10 as it is in base 2, then group can hold 10.
Say I print fw.group, I want to see that number 10 displayed in the screen. I want group to hold 2 bits only, but I want the program to treat 10 as it is in base 2,not 10. @David Bowling

Comment: Yes. Read [@StoryTeller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905594/how-can-i-represent-all-the-possible-values-of-n-bits-in-base-2-using-n-bits-in#comment72911368_42905594): no binary integer constants in Standard C. There is a Gnu extension for this: `fw.group = 0b10;`.

Comment: I think here the real question is: where that data (10) came form? user input? Literals..? Are you allowed to use Hex? If yes: `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03` and that's it

Comment: If you simply want to be able to display the binary value held in `fw.group`, store decimal `2`, and convert to a binary string for display.

Comment: Thank you.
When I wrote:
fw.group = 2;
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:17: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
      fw.group = 2;
                 ^
@David Bowling

Comment: As already sad:make it `unsigned`

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why. 2 in binary is 10, which is 2 bits wide, so why would I get this error? @LPs

Comment: Otherwise you lose a bit for the sign...

Comment: Thank you very much!
So if I write 
fw.group = 10;
while So if I write 
fw.group = 10;
while group is unsigned, I get this warning:
main.c:21:17: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-WovSo if I write 
fw.group = 10;
while group is unsigned, I get this warning:
main.c:21:17: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
      fw.group = 10;
                 overflow]
      fw.group = 10;
                 ^~uhgroup is unsigned
and when I print fw.group I get 2 @LPs

Comment: Take alook at [this  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527500/3436922)

Comment: `int group  :2;` can store the values [-2 , 1] or [0 , 3].  It is implementation defined.  Better to use `unsigned group  :2;` to store [0 , 3] or `signed group  :2;` to store [-2 , 1] .  It is a place in C where bare `int` might not act like `signed int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your binary number to decimal before storing it.Like convert binary `10` to `2` before storing in `group`.

I wanted to comment this but couldnt due to low reputation.

Edit-
If you are using c++, you can convert it directly using `0b`.
Example-

`0b1` means binary 1 or decimal 0

`0b10` means binary 10 or deciaml 2

`0b100` means binary 100 or decimal 4

Or in standard C you can make a function that takes `binary format` integer like `10` in our case and returns converted decimal value `2`. Later you can retrieve your bits using bitwisee operations like shifts.

Comment: Thank you!
I think I don't understand it yet.
Can you please give an example? @monster