# overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow] in class member initializer only on one constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

There has been several similar questions, but this one could(?) be due to a bug in the compiler of gcc. The only const is the parameter vvalue. I have changed to char* and still got the same compiler warning.

This is a third party code with class (not showing namespace etc. 
Only showing relevant part

```
class Value {
public:
    ....
    Value(double value);
    Value(const char *vvalue);
    ....
private:
        struct CommentInfo {
          CommentInfo();
           ~CommentInfo();
          void setComment( const char *text );
           char *comment_;
      };

        union ValueHolder {
          Int int_;
           UInt uint_;
           double real_;
           bool bool_;
           char *string_;
 #ifdef JSON_VALUE_USE_INTERNAL_MAP
           ValueInternalArray *array_;
          ValueInternalMap *map_;
 #else
         ObjectValues *map_;
 #endif
        } value_;
        ValueType type_ : 8;
        int allocated_ : 1;     // Notes: if declared as bool, bitfield is useless.
 #ifdef JSON_VALUE_USE_INTERNAL_MAP
       unsigned int itemIsUsed_ : 1;      // used by the ValueInternalMap container.
        int memberNameIsStatic_ : 1;       // used by the ValueInternalMap container.
 #endif
        CommentInfo *comments_;
     };

};

/// class definition
 316 Value::Value( double value )
 317    : type_( realValue )
 318    , comments_(nullptr)
 319 # ifdef JSON_VALUE_USE_INTERNAL_MAP
 320    , itemIsUsed_( 0 )
 321 #endif
 322 {
 323    value_.real_ = value;
 324 }
 325 
 326 Value::Value(const char *vvalue)
 327    : type_(stringValue), allocated_(true),
 328       comments_(nullptr)
 329 #ifdef JSON_VALUE_USE_INTERNAL_MAP
 330       , itemIsUsed_( 0 )
 331 #endif 
 332 {     
 333    value_.string_ = duplicateStringValue(vvalue);
 334 }
```

When we run with -Werror -Wall we get the following error message only with the constructor taking inputs but not other constructors for the comments_ member:

```
json_value.cpp:328:24: error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]
       comments_(nullptr)
                        ^
```

Strange enough the warning does not occur on the constructor with (double value) version. I have stared at the code for a long time and don't see where I can change to eliminate this warning.

This may have something to do with the bit field:

```
 309 Value::Value( double value )
 310    : type_( realValue ),
 311    //allocated_(true), // adding this caused overflow issue
 312    //allocated_(1), // adding this caused overflow issue
 313    //allocated_(0), // this eliminates overflow issue
 314    allocated_(false), // this eliminates overflow issue
 315    comments_(nullptr)
```

What I found, the warning has something to do with the bit field in previous class member: alocated_ which is a 1 bit for boolean.  Not sure the code is a bad practice or what.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The bit field `allocated_` can hold two values. In your implementation, they are `0` and `-1`. [See this question for why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527387/signed-bit-field-represetation) You are initializing it with `true`, which converts to `1`, which overflows. Turning on `-Wconversion` explains this nicely:

> warning: conversion from 'int' to 'signed char:1' changes value from '1' to '-1' [-Wconversion]

Update: The overflow warning also has this detail. Both have that detail from gcc 8.1 onwards. This third party library appears to be jsoncpp, and this bug appears to have been fixed with commit 2bc6137a on Jan 24, 2015 ([ref](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/commit/2bc6137ada4195be3a737c3d9410eaa60ec13a10)) and included in v1.4.0 released Feb 11, 2015 ([ref](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/releases/tag/1.4.0)).