# autoconf: check for offset of a member

Tags: c, autoconf

I have a structure:

```
struct foo {
  struct {
     int a;
     int b;
     long len;
     unsigned short c;
     unsigned short d;
  };
  char payload[1024];
} bar;
```

I want to find out, at configure time, if I need to insert padding to make 'payload' double-aligned.

Autoconf provides `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(type)` and `AC_CHECK_ALIGNOF(type)`, but what I really need is something like `AC_CHECK_OFFSETOF(type, member)`.   If the reported offset was not double-aligned, I could introduce enough padding to make it so.

I could run a little test program that reported `offsetof(struct bar, payload)`, but I don't want to introduce a run-time check into my build system (we cross-compile not infrequently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [zero length bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297095/practical-use-of-zero-length-bitfields) might solve this problem without autotool tricks.

```
struct foo {
  struct {
     int a;
     int b;
     long len;
     unsigned short c;
     unsigned short d;
  };
  int64_t : 0; // or long long whatever integer type is sizeof(double)
  char payload[1024];
} bar;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about zero length bitfields.  If I'm reading the XNU example right, though, I want to use double : 0 ?

Comment: @RobLatham Unless you have a compiler that has floating-point bitfields as some sort of extension, bitfields must be an integer type...

Comment: @RobLatham It needs an integer type so `long` or `int64_t` might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for offering an approach that involves no configure magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AC_COMPUTE_INT`:

```
AC_COMPUTE_INT([payload_offset], [offsetof(struct bar, payload)], ...)
```

But it would probably be easier just to use an anonymous union to force alignment:

```
struct foo {
  struct {
     int a;
     int b;
     long len;
     unsigned short c;
     unsigned short d;
  };
  union {
    char payload[1024];
    double dummy; /* for alignment */
  };
} bar;
```

If you don't want to use a union, you can compute the padding in place:

```
struct foo {
  struct header {
     int a;
     int b;
     long len;
     unsigned short c;
     unsigned short d;
  };
  char padding[(alignof(double) - 1) - ((sizeof(struct header)
      + alignof(double) - 1) % alignof(double))];
  char payload[1024];
} bar;
```

Comment: Of the two approaches, zero-width bitfields or stashing into a union, which one is the more standard way, if one can say such a thing, to do so?

Comment: @RobLatham a zero-width bitfield can force padding to the alignment of an integral type, but not a floating-point type.  Anonymous unions are part of the standard (6.7.2.1p13) as of C11, and have wide support.

Comment: we still try pretty hard to maintain c89, but maybe a named union will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I chose the zero-width bitfield approach since it's available in older c environments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that autoconf can tell you that, as it is a matter of the compiler who decides to add padding or not.  So I would think that the only reasonable way would be to compile a program that checks if offset of the member equals to what you think it should be equal.

Comment: no doubt the answer is entirely up to the compiler.  AC_CHECK_SIZEOF and AC_CHECK_ALIGNOF determine the answer exactly as you suggest: by compiling a program.  The trick I'm missing is how to get the answer without running that program.

Comment: Well, use a static assert then, that would break a program at the compile time.  Something like:
char x [(expr) ? 1 : -1];