# Different types for zero length bit fields in c?

Tags: c, bit-fields

Fount this statement *A zero-width bit field can cause the next field to be aligned on the next container boundary where the container is the same size as the underlying type of the bit field*

To put it into practice assuming int is 2 bytes (16 bits) and that short is 1 byte (8 bits) to save typing. Also let's say we are using the gcc compiler (would be nice to explain the differences to clang).

```
struct foo {
    unsigned int a:5;
    unsigned int :0;
    unsigned int b:3;
}
```

In memory this looks like

```
struct address
   |            
   |
   v
   aaaaa000 00000000 bbb00000 00000000
```

Question 1: In my understanding it can *not* look like `aaaaa000 00000000 0..00bbb00000...`, So `bbb` has to align with the container *directly* following the current container. Is this actually true?

Moving on, if I specify

```
struct bar {
    unsigned short x:5; 
    unsigned int :0;
    unsigned short y:7;
}
```

Will it be like so?

```
struct address
   | short stops here         short starts  
   |      |                   |   
   v      v | this is uint  | v              
   xxxxx000 00000000 00000000 yyyyyyy0
```

**Edit 1**
It was pointed out that short can not be less than 16 bytes. That is slightly beside the point in this question. But if its important to you you can replace `short` with `char` and `int` with `short`

Comment: Which compiler? Bitfields have a lot of implementation-specific details.

Comment: Even bitfields get padding for alignment during type switches, so your sample isn't right.

Comment: *assuming [...] short is 1 byte (8 bits)* `short` cannot be 8 bits, the Standard requires it to be at least 16-bit.

Comment: @ouah do you think I should edit the question? It doesn't seem to really alter the meaning.

Comment: @user10607 you may edit it and replace your `unsigned short` with `unsigned char` and add an edit note at the end of the question.

Comment: @user10607 "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed
int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type." and _Bool may not be the same as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @black well other types are definitely allowed as shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298148/1073672

Comment: @user10607 yes but it's implementation defined. Using `:0` is ok, if you referred to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, after reading the text [in context](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03defbitf.htm):

The result of your example (corrected to use `char`):

```
struct bar {
    unsigned char x:5; 
    unsigned int :0;
    unsigned char y:7;
}
```

would look like this (assuming 16-bit `int`):

```
 char pad pad      int boundary
  |    |   |        |
  v    v   v        v       
  xxxxx000 00000000 yyyyyyy0
```

(I'm ignoring endian).

The zero-length bitfield causes the position to move to next `int` boundary. You defined `int` to be 16-bit, so 16 minus 5 gives 11 bits of padding.

It does *not* insert an entire blank `int`. The example on the page you link demonstrates this (but using 32-bit integers).

Comment: Here is the link for context http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03defbitf.htm

Comment: I did some more reading and your answer fits the big picture nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

First, whenever writing bit-fields, it is always recommended that you declare variables either in ascending or descending sizes of datatypes used. This way compiler always chooses the highest datatype size and it makes chunks of the same size.

This is what i think will be.

```
struct address
| short stops here         short starts  
|    |                   |   
v   v| this is unit      | v              
xxxxx000 00000000 00000000 yyyyyyy0
```

Comment: First, I don't believe that's a valid recommendation *unless* your only goal is to minimize space. Sometimes bit fields are used to match an externally imposed layout. Second, I don't believe this answers the question.