# Is a undefined behavior for C++ that empty struct with zero-width bit-field tagged align attr?

Tags: c++, clang++

I have follow wired code. It run failed with clang++, and worked with g++.
In aarch64, `long long int` is `8 bytes`, and the `struct S94` is `16 bytes`(why? Seem in x86-64 is `1 byte`).

I see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field , but it hasn't this case.

I guess is a undefined behavior or implementation-defined, cause it's so wired, but not have evidence.

Anyone can explain this code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern void *memset (void *__s, int __c, size_t __n);

typedef long long int Talllong __attribute__((aligned));

struct  S94 {
    Talllong: 0;
};

struct S94 s94;

void check94va(int z, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, z);
    struct S94 arg1 =  va_arg(ap, struct S94);
    long long int tmp = va_arg(ap, long long);
    //printf("result = %lld\n", tmp);
    if (tmp != 2LL) {
        printf("Fails!!!!\n");
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void) {
    memset(&s94, '\0', sizeof(s94));
    //printf("sizeof(s94) = %ld\n", sizeof(s94));
    check94va(1, s94, 2LL);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Edited: I know it's a unconventional C++ code, not follow some practice rule. But what I'm concerned about is whether it meets the standard, and whether compiler guaranteed the result.

Comment: *"wired code"* should be "weird code"? Could you explain in words why you think it's weird? What details should people be on the lookout for when they read your code?

Comment: Are you asking about the [0-width bit field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297095/practical-use-of-zero-length-bitfields)?

Comment: Are you even writing C++:?  you are only including "C" headers, and memset, va_arg are hardly every used in C++.  In general just stay away from `bit_field` they probably don't do what you think they're doing anyway (you can't control memory layout at the bit level. bit_fields only take care that calculations behave as if the bitfield has n bytes and compilers are completely free on how to achieve that illusion. Just use bitmasking/shifting if you want control over bits.

Comment: bit fields widely used in cases where structure is related to particular architecture  and\or hardware. They allow enough control within one, but they aren't portable. But yeah, that's a touchy topic. And that should be C++, for C any bit field that isn't unsigned or int are illegal.

Comment: @Wyck not sure why answer there is calling this "hacky" way. It's a well-defined way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a field of size 0 means that this and next field would have a memory location of next allocation unit boundary. In C++ for platforms with strict aligment requiremnts that unit would be of size `sizeof(Talllong)` (in C, afaik, it's undefined,might be `sizeof(int)` because field slarger than `unsigned int` aren't supported).

As a result the beginning of struct, field with zero 0 and the end of struct have to have 3 distinct addresses, aligned by 8 bytes because next adjacent instance of `S94`  struct should start at unique aligned address. That makes size of struct to be 16.

x86-64 doesn't have allocation unit alignment requrements. This makes two first addresses same and struct would have the minimum possible size of `char`.

You should use portable C11's `alignas` isntead of compiler specific C-ism to ensure alignment, `__attribute__((aligned))` isn't strict.

```
/* usually aligment is NOT requred in this case and is an extension.
   :0 does it automatically.
*/
typedef long long int Talllong /*alignas(long long int)*/;

struct alignas(64) S94 {
    Talllong w11: 4;
    /* Adding up to 8 bytes of fields here won't change size */
    Talllong: 0; 
    /* Adding up to 8 bytes of fields here won't change size */
    Talllong w21: 12;
    Talllong w22:  3;
};
```

It's not defined what alignment attributes do to bit fields because they don't have unique memory location and you can't take address of them. Compiler may ignore these attributes, display diagnostics or perform an "intuitively" natural change.

Note: order and position of bitfields within a single memory location is not reguated by standard, it's typically defined by platform and compiler.
One of common changes is that little-endian and big-endian platforms order fields in opposing directions.

Comment: Thx your reply. C++ 17 draft 10.6.2 [dcl.align] say alignment-specifier shall not be applied to bit-field. But I still want to know whether __attribute__((aligned)) can apply to bit-field?

Comment: @hstk both gcc and clang support both as extension, as well as `packed` attribute   (`__attribute__` is not related to standard) for containing struct. Behaviour (might be) differen't. It doesn't matter in this case, 0-sized field is always aligned in relation to struct.